# How to get all strings from all nested tags of a xml tag with python's lxml.etree library?

Tags: python, xml, string, lxml, elementtree

I have an xml file in which it is possible that the following occurs:

```
...
<a><b>This is</b> some text about <c>some</c> issue I have, parsing xml</a>
...
```

Edit: Let's assume, the tags could be nested more than only level, meaning

```
<a><b><c>...</c>...</b>...</a>
```

I came up with this using the python lxml.etree library.

```
context = etree.iterparse(PATH_TO_XML, dtd_validation=True, events=("end",))
for event, element in context:
    tag = element.tag
    if tag == "a":
        print element.text # is empty :/
        mystring = element.xpath("string()")
        ...
```

But somehow it goes wrong.

What I want is the whole string

```
"This is some text about some issue I have, parsing xml"
```

But I only get an empty string. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked many times.

You can use `lxml.html.text_content()` method.

```
import lxml.html
t = lxml.html.fromstring("...")
t.text_content()
```

REF: [Filter out HTML tags and resolve entities in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486/filter-out-html-tags-and-resolve-entities-in-python)

OR use `lxml.etree.strip_tags()` method.

REF: [In lxml, how do I remove a tag but retain all contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681317/in-lxml-how-do-i-remove-a-tag-but-retain-all-contents)