# Remove all javascript tags and style tags from html with python and the lxml module

Tags: python, html, lxml

I am parsing an html document using the http://lxml.de/ library. So far I have figured out how to strip tags from an html document [In lxml, how do I remove a tag but retain all contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681317/in-lxml-how-do-i-remove-a-tag-but-retain-all-contents) but the method described in that post leaves all the text, stripping the  tags with out removing the actual script. I have also found a class reference to lxml.html.clean.Cleaner http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html but this is clear as mud as to how to actually use the class to clean the document.  Any help, perhaps a short example would be helpful to me!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Below is an example to do what you want. For an HTML document, `Cleaner` is a better general solution to the problem than using `strip_elements`, because in cases like this you want to strip out more than just the `<script>` tag; you also want to get rid of things like `onclick=function()` attributes on other tags.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import lxml
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

cleaner = Cleaner()
cleaner.javascript = True # This is True because we want to activate the javascript filter
cleaner.style = True      # This is True because we want to activate the styles & stylesheet filter

print("WITH JAVASCRIPT & STYLES")
print(lxml.html.tostring(lxml.html.parse('http://www.google.com')))
print("WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT & STYLES")
print(lxml.html.tostring(cleaner.clean_html(lxml.html.parse('http://www.google.com'))))
```

You can get a list of the options you can set in the [lxml.html.clean.Cleaner documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html); some options you can just set to `True` or `False` (the default) and others take a list like:

```
cleaner.kill_tags = ['a', 'h1']
cleaner.remove_tags = ['p']
```

Note that the difference between kill vs remove:

```
remove_tags:
  A list of tags to remove. Only the tags will be removed, their content will get pulled up into the parent tag.
kill_tags:
  A list of tags to kill. Killing also removes the tag's content, i.e. the whole subtree, not just the tag itself.
allow_tags:
  A list of tags to include (default include all).
```

Comment: I've been out most of the day, should have brought this up earlier I guess. I just noticed after playing with this that the kill_tags thing doesn't seem to actually do anything for example I added `cleaner.kill_tags = ('img','noscript','a')` but those tags remain in the output document, the rest of the example above works as expected, it's just after playing with kill tags that I noticed this.

Comment: Notice in my example I use square brackets, not parentheses. You should try `['img','noscript','a']`. The square brackets denote a list, whereas the parentheses denote a tuple (in your example a 3-element tuple). Tuples and lists are not the same at all.

Comment: I tried both list and tuple, notations the effect is the same, the tags are not removed. After some further research I believe this is a bug in the version of lxml/html/clean.py distributed with ubuntu. Note at line 253 of http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean-pysrc.html kill_tags is initialized to `kill_tags = set(self.kill_tags or ())` in the version  of clean.py shipped with Ubuntu its just initialized to  `kill_tags = set()`. Rendering it ineffectual. Thanks I will notify the package maintainer.

Comment: it is not working for url like :

http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2016/03/attack-of-week-apple-imessage.html

Comment: cleaner really is the thing!

Answer (score 7):

Here are some examples of how to remove and parse different types of HTML elements from a XML/HTML tree.

KEY SUGGESTION: Its helpful to ***NOT*** depend on *external libraries* and do **everything** within "native python 2/3 code".

Here are some examples of how to do this with "native" python...

```
# (REMOVE <SCRIPT> to </script> and variations)
pattern = r'<[ ]*script.*?\/[ ]*script[ ]*>'  # mach any char zero or more times
text = re.sub(pattern, '', text, flags=(re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))

# (REMOVE HTML <STYLE> to </style> and variations)
pattern = r'<[ ]*style.*?\/[ ]*style[ ]*>'  # mach any char zero or more times
text = re.sub(pattern, '', text, flags=(re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))

# (REMOVE HTML <META> to </meta> and variations)
pattern = r'<[ ]*meta.*?>'  # mach any char zero or more times
text = re.sub(pattern, '', text, flags=(re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))

# (REMOVE HTML COMMENTS <!-- to --> and variations)
pattern = r'<[ ]*!--.*?--[ ]*>'  # mach any char zero or more times
text = re.sub(pattern, '', text, flags=(re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))

# (REMOVE HTML DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html to > and variations)
pattern = r'<[ ]*\![ ]*DOCTYPE.*?>'  # mach any char zero or more times
text = re.sub(pattern, '', text, flags=(re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))
```

NOTE:

```
re.IGNORECASE # is needed to match case sensitive <script> or <SCRIPT> or <Script>
re.MULTILINE # is needed to match newlines
re.DOTALL # is needed to match "special characters" and match "any character"
```

I've tested this out on several different HTML files and  including , ,  and   and it works "fast" and works across newlines!..

NOTE: It also does **NOT** depend on beautifulsoup or any other external downloaded library!

Hope this helps!

:)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [strip_elements](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_elements) method to remove scripts, then use [strip_tags](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_tags) method to remove other tags:

```
etree.strip_elements(fragment, 'script')
etree.strip_tags(fragment, 'a', 'p') # and other tags that you want to remove
```

Comment: For an HTML document when removing scripts you want to get rid of ALL the javascript, not just the `<script>` tags themselves, so Cleaner is a [better general solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8554251/462302), though `strip_elements` is fine for an XML document.

Comment: Thanks... your answer is still a good solution for XML documents, so I added some text in my answer to clarify the XML vs HTML use cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bs4 libray also for this purpose.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_src, "lxml")
[x.extract() for x in soup.findAll(['script', 'style'])]
```

Comment: surely this does the opposite / what do you do with this list?

Comment: No, because it changes ```soup``` in the process. Ie soup no longer has these tags

Answer (score 0):

**You can use *Regular Expression* With Ease**

*For Javasript*

```py
def remove_script_code(data):
    clean = re.compile('<script>.*?</script>')
    return [re.sub(clean, '', data)]
```

*For CSS Style*

```py
def remove_style_code(data):
    clean = re.compile('<style>.*?</style>')
    return [re.sub(clean, '', data)]
```