# Remove multiple lines in files

Tags: python

I have multiple HTML files where I have to remove some lines inside.

The lines I need to remove don't have a keyword at the beginning and at the end except for the script tags, but I don't want to remove all of the script tags in these files.

Example of the HTML part i need to remove:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Do you think it's possible to do, and if so how?

**Update**

I made some modifications to the @ARJMP solution below, but it returns the same file again without removing the analytics tag in the regex.

Regex is correct by @ARJMP https://regex101.com/r/rWLZRD/1

Why is regex not subtracting?

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

ga_re = r"<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\s+var _gaq = _gaq .*</script>"  # our regex to subtract google analytics script
file_texts = defaultdict(str)  # Temp store for file text
file_paths = ['index.html']  # list of files you want to run

for file_path in file_paths:
    with open(file_path, mode='r+') as fin:
        # Extract text from file
        file_text = ''.join(fin.readlines())
        file_texts[file_path] = file_text

        # Write to backup file
        with open('{}.backup'.format(file_path), mode='w+') as fbackup:
            fbackup.write(file_text)
    with open(file_path, mode='w+') as fout:
        # Perform regex sub and write to file
        file_text = file_texts[file_path]
        file_text_result = re.sub(ga_re, '', file_text, re.DOTALL) 
        fout.write(file_text_result)
```

Comment: Could you please explain which lines need to be removed in another way, perhaps an example would work well?

Comment: How do you specifically want to choose which lines you want to remove? How have you tried going about it already?

Comment: You’ll probably want to use a tool for working with HTML, like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Python is a general purpose language so, yes, it's possible.

Comment: @mattjegan I need to remove or comment out all of the code in the example.

@SCB I have tried using some simple if such as `if line.startswith('<script type="text/javascript">'):` to capture the first tag and the same for the end tag but I do not know how to to get the content between these 2 tags/lines or to add a line before and after to comment out it, I'm a little new with Python.

Comment: @Fusecube so to clarify you want to get rid of all scripts in the document?

Comment: @Fusecube this answer is likely to be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554251/1277637

Comment: @mattjegan no not all scripts just this google analytics script.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex solution, though regex is not the best way to do this, considering your very simple use case this could be used to solve your problem.

The regex that checks for the script tag followed by `var _gaq = _gaq`, and ending with the first occurence of `</script>`

https://regex101.com/r/rWLZRD/1

```
import re

regex = r"<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\s+var _gaq = _gaq .*</script>"

test_str = ("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
    "var _gaq = _gaq || [];\n"
    "_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);\n"
    "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);\n"
    "(function() {\n"
    "var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;\n"
    "ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';\n"
    "var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);\n"
    "})();\n"
    "</script>")

matches = re.sub(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL)
```

Ok, so you also need to do this for multiple files which you could do with a script that iterates over a list of files and applies the regex.  This script will also generate a {file}.backup because it modifies the original files.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

ga_re = r"<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\s+var _gaq = _gaq .*</script>"  # our regex to subtract google analytics script
file_texts = defaultdict(str)  # Temp store for file text
file_paths = ['first_file.html', 'second_file.html']  # list of files you want to run

for file_path in file_paths:
    with open(file_path, mode='r') as f:
        # Extract text from file
        file_text = ''.join(f.readlines())
        file_texts[file_path] = file_text

        # Write to backup file
        with open('{}.backup'.format(file_path), mode='w+') as fbackup:
            fbackup.write(file_text)
    with open(file_path, mode='w+'):
        # Perform regex sub and write to file
        file_text = file_texts[file_path]
        file_text_result = re.sub(ga_re, file_text, re.DOTALL) 
        f.write(file_text_result)
```

You could also use something like argparse to make a command line script which could accept a list of filenames on the command line, provide options to create or not create backups, etc.  but that's outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_analytics.py", line 5, in <module>
    file_texts = defaultdict('')  # Temp store for file text
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None`
Never used defaultdict before and can't get this to work.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `file_texts = defaultdict(str)`.  You probably don't even really need defaultdict and could use a regular dict instead if you prefer.