# insert whitespace when stripping html tags using lxml

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want to insert whitespace into the resulting text when I strip tags and extract text using `lxml`

I don't really know `lxml`. Via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093792/1599229) (which seems based on a comment on the same page from @bluu), I have the following:

```
import lxml

def strip_html(s):
    return str(lxml.html.fromstring(s).text_content())
```

When I try it with this:

```
strip_html("<p>This what you want.</p><p>This what you get.</p>")
```

I get this:

```
'This what you want.This what you get.'
```

But I want this:

```
'This what you want. This what you get.'
```

What I really want is the equivalent of this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = "<p>This what you want.</p><p>This what you get.</p>"

BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml").get_text(separator=" ")
```

which does give the desired output - for all tags - but I want to avoid the amazing `BeautifulSoup` in this case

I also want it to work for all tags, and without my having to spell out all the tags, or loop and search for particular characters etc

I have looked at the code of `bs4`'s `element.py` to try to adapt the `separator` and I see it's not a simple matter

I was also looking at `lxml.html.clean` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554251/1599229)

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'lxml_html' is not defined`. What lxml version are you using?

Comment: @QHarr apologies: fixed typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select all tags that contains text iterate over these and `join()` the `ResultSet` by seperator:

```
s = "<p>This what you want.</p><p>This what you get.</p>"
' '.join([e.text_content() for e in lxml.html.document_fromstring(s).xpath("//*[text()]")])
```

###### Example

```
import lxml

def strip_html(s):
    return ' '.join([e.text_content() for e in lxml.html.document_fromstring(s).xpath("//*[text()]")])

strip_html("<p>This what you want.</p><p>This what you get.</p>")
```

###### Output

```
This what you want. This what you get.
```